# Verify emails accounts without getting black listed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, smtp

I just used the email_verifier gem (https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier) to check if a list of emails was valid (ie. email account exists on a given server). Unfortunately this has blacklisted my own IP on several servers since it turns out that this gem pretends to send email.

Is there a (different) way to verify that an email account exists without getting blacklisted?

Comment: not really.  only way to tell if an address is valid (outside of being semantically correct/valid) is to try and deliver to it. and even then it isn't 100% accurate, since just because a mail server accepts the message doesn't mean it will get delivered.  What are you trying to do with the information if it is valid or not?  normally you would send an email using something like VERP, and then check for which ones bounce.  Even then it is not fool proof.

Comment: also in looking at the source of that gem  there are lots of cases where it would fail, specifically in the change the domain doesn't have an MX record.

Comment: Could you imagine how much more efficient spammers would be if such a tool existed?!!

Comment: You could try relaying the verification emails through an smtp service like sendgrid.  It's a bit like 'passing the blacklisting buck', but this is the service they provide and they're setup to handle IPs getting blacklisted much better than we are.